# SetEnvIf not working on specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I've got a password protected site, and I'm trying to allow a specific URL through so that it works for a Payment callback. The site is built using CakePHP.

The below works great however the `Allow from env=allow` is just not being taken into account (I've tried with my own IP address too). The `setenvif` mod is enabled in Apache and the other "Allow from" lines work fine. FYI it's running on Ubuntu on EC2. I've also searched on the site for similar issues and solutions but to no avail.

I've checked the `$_SERVER` global array in PHP for the "allow" environment variable and it exists so running out of ideas. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/secure_trading/callback allow=1
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/secure_trading/callback$ allow=1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/secure_trading/callback" allow=1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/app/weboot/secure_trading/callback" allow=1

AuthName "Protected"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/domain.co.uk/.htpasswd

Order deny,allow
Satisfy Any
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from env=allow
require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is it that you are trying to make a specific action public?

Comment: @Antuan yes that's correct

Comment: you could use the Auth component to manage which action should be allowed versus not allowed, plus also check the ipaddress (which could be the local environment ip) to allow access. I'm not sure why it doesn't using the .htaccess file

Comment: `SetEnvIf Request_URI "/app/weboot/secure_trading/callback"` Is the "weboot" part supposed to be "webroot"?